# Accessing part of y_pred in customized loss function for calculating loss

Tags: python, keras, embedding

I want to develop a neural network with three inputs pos,anc,neg and three outputs pos_out,anc_out,neg_out. While calculating loss in my customized loss function in keras, I want to access pos_out, anc_out, neg_out in y_pred. I can access y_pred as a whole. But how to access individual part pos_out, anc_out and neg_out

I have applied max function to y_pred. It calculates max value correctly. If I am passing only one output in Model as Model(input=[pos,anc,neg], output=pos_out) then also it calculates max value correctly. But when it comes to accessing max values form pos_out, anc_out and neg_out separately in customized function, it does not work.

```
def testmodel(input_shape):

    pos = Input(shape=(14,300))
    anc = Input(shape=(14,300))
    neg = Input(shape=(14,300))

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(batch_input_shape=(1,14,300)))

    pos_out = model(pos)
    anc_out = model(anc)
    neg_out = model(neg)


    model = Model(input=[pos,anc,neg], output=[pos_out,anc_out,neg_out])

    return model

def customloss(y_true,y_pred):
  print((K.int_shape(y_pred)[1]))
  #loss = K.max((y_pred))
  loss = K.max[pos_out]
  return loss
```

Comment: you don't have any trainable layers in your model...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loss function that contains a closure that lets you access the model and thus the targets and the model layer outputs.

```
class ExampleCustomLoss(object):
  """ The loss function can access model.inputs, model.targets and the outputs
  of specific layers. These are all tensors and will have the expected results
  for the batch.
  """
  def __init__(self, model):
    self.model = model

  def loss(self, y_true, y_pred, **kwargs):
    ...
    return loss


model = Model(..., ...)
loss_calculator = ExampleCustomLoss(model)
model.compile('adam', loss_calculator.loss)
```

However, it may be simpler to do the inverse. i.e. have a single model output

```
out = Concatenate(axis=1)([pos_out, anc_out, neg_out])
```

And then in the loss function slice y_true and y_pred.

From the names of variables, it looks as if you are trying to use a triplet loss. You may find this other question useful:
[How to deal with triplet loss when at time of input i have only two files i.e. at time of testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716616/how-to-deal-with-triplet-loss-when-at-time-of-input-i-have-only-two-files-i-e-a/56719657#56719657)

Answer (score 0):

Your loss function gets 2 arguments, model output and true label, your model output will have the shape that you define when you define the net. Your loss function needs to output a single difference value, between your model's output and the true value of the label while training.

Also please add some trainable layers to your model, because your custom loss function will be useless otherwise.